# Spring Security: move method security annotations out of code

Tags: spring-security

I have gone through the Spring Security video [on this page](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Spring-Security-3).

Around 36:30 he talks about securing methods using security annotations along with the method signature as shown below:

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
public String create();
```

Why do we need to keep the annotations along with the method? (since security annotations do not *have anything* to do with what the method does)

Can I get these annotations out into a separate file so that I can change them without modifying the actual code? (probably using something like Spring AOP features)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it thanks to Spring AOP:

```
<global-method-security>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* com.domain.service.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_USER"/>
</global-method-security>
```

Ajust expression to your needs.

**XML declarations** are good from **flexibility** point of view. Consider following cases:

- you want to reuse some service in two modules but you want to have different security rules.
- you want apply some security restriction on per package basis

It is possible only with XML.

**Annotations** are good from **readability** point of view. When you see some method then you can view all security restrictions directly. No need to open some XML file each time and think about expressions (is it applied for this method?). So it's easy.

Do not mix both approaches. It's so confusing. Check your needs and choose the best one for you project.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. If I use Shiro inside a Spring project, can I still do away with method security annotations using Spring AOP?

Comment: I do not have experiance with Apache Shiro, so I do not know. But I am sure that it's must be possible. May be you need to rewrite this Spring Security XML with some more low level Spring AOP xml. Or may be Apache Shiro provides something similar out of the box.